# Total registrado no Banco de dados com Script

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

minha página php usa os seguintes arquivos "1-config.php = faz conexão com o banco de dados" "2-total.php = conecta com o Form e mostra o total de registro na página"

no Html da minha página principal eu uso `<?php require_once("total.php"); ?>`, agora entra o problema, tenho um script no fim da página que controla uma das funções da minha página

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function verifica() {
    for (var a = 0; a < 39; a++) {
        var b = "s" + (a + 1),
            c = document.getElementById(b);
        if (c.innerHTML = segsToTime(c.getAttribute("inicial")), verificaCookie(b)) {
            var d = new Date,
                e = d.getTime() - getCookie(b),
                f = c.getAttribute("inicial") - parseInt(e / 1e3);
            c.innerHTML = segsToTime(f), f < 0 && (c.innerHTML = segsToTime(c.getAttribute("inicial")), invalidarCookie(b))
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        verifica()
    }, 1e3)
}

function dispara(a) {
    var b = document.getElementById(a),
        c = new Date,
        d = c.getTime();
    c.setTime(c.getTime() + 2e3 * b.getAttribute("inicial")), document.cookie = a + "=" + d + "; path=/"
}

function lerCookie(a) {
    var b = document.cookie.split("=");
    return b[1]
}

function verificaCookie(a) {
    return document.cookie.indexOf(a) != -1
}

function getCookie(a) {
    var b = document.cookie,
        c = a + "=",
        d = b.indexOf("; " + c);
    if (d == -1) {
        if (d = b.indexOf(c), 0 != d) return null
    } else d += 2;
    var e = b.indexOf(";", d);
    return e == -1 && (e = b.length), unescape(b.substring(d + c.length, e))
}

function invalidarCookie(a) {
    document.cookie = a + "=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/"
}

function segsToTime(a) {
    return h = parseInt(a / 3600), h < 10 && (h = "0" + h), m = parseInt(a / 60 % 60), m < 10 && (m = "0" + m), s = parseInt(a % 60), s < 10 && (s = "0" + s), h + ":" + m + ":" + s
}
verifica();
</script>
```

o problema é, como eu posso colocar o total de registro do bd pra que fique automático como o resto da página? sem precisar migrar o script pra php tipo "echo("...resto do código")" tem como fazer alguma coisa no próprio html dentro do script?

EX:`function verifica(){for(var a=0;a<"total";a++)...resto do código`

ou

EX:`function verifica(){for(var a=0;a<"<?php require_once("total.php");?>";a++)...resto do código`(já tentei assim)

Obrigado.

Comment: Se você rodar um jsbeautifier.org nesses códigos vai facilitar muito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acho que vc já tem o total dado por $x então:

function verifica(){for(var a=0;a<<?php echo $x ?>;a++)...resto do código

Comment: nossa... ele ficou com 1 ha mais, como se ele terminasse a sequencia e acrescentasse mais um. tem alguma macete pra arrumar?

Comment: resolvi !! $x-1 ;) Ty mano!!!

Comment: dá lhe garoto!!! :)

Comment: o <?php echo $x ?> perde o valor não sei pq... ele da o numero do registro porém a função que depende disso não funciona direito.